# Saving user_id with new entity, but in database user_id is null

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

This is how I'm trying to add user_id. The request passes my request rules where's user_id is required, if I remove the line where I add user_id it fails. user_id is added in my model's fillable array. Any idea where should I look for the problem? :/

```
    public function store()
    {
        $this->crud->getRequest()->request->add(['user_id' => backpack_user()->id]);
        $response = $this->traitStore();
        return $response;
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $this->crud->getRequest()->request->add(['user_id' => backpack_user()->id]);
        $response = $this->traitUpdate();
        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: what is your backpack version?

Comment: It's the newest: 4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have added the value but not the field ...

you should add the field too:

```
public function store()
    {
        $this->crud->getRequest()->request->add(['user_id' => backpack_user()->id]);

  $this->crud->addField(["name" => "user_id","type" => "hidden"]);
        $response = $this->traitStore();
        return $response;
    }
```

and the same goes for update ...
make sure you do not have another filed with name 'user_id'

Comment: I've added this line now I get error: Call to a member function getRelated() on null

Comment: this is another error ... need more info ... probably something wrong in your model relation ... should debug it ..

Comment: Ohh yes, I forgot return before belongsTo. Sir, thank your for your help, much appreciated!